# C++ class implementation with variable types from other header files

Tags: c++

Given this current setup, how can I implement this so that I can avoid including any header files in the `file.h` header file?

file.h:

```
#ifndef __FILE_H__
#define __FILE_H__

class foo {
    private:
        Vector vector; // std::vector from <vector>
        Map map; // std::map from <map>
    public:
        void bar();
};

#endif
```

file.cpp:

```
#include "file.h"

void foo::bar()
{
    // Do something with private variables...
}
```

main.cpp

```
#inclue "file.h"

int main()
{
    foo var;
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: Isn't it recommended to reduce the number of header inclusions in a header file?

Comment: `#define __FILE_H__` That identifier is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it yourself, the program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @Locklan no, it's recommended to include the header files as soon you need them (as with your case), and to use forward declarations where possible.

Comment: It is recommended. But you can't forward declare standard library templates. So make an exception for standard headers. There's too many of them as it is. And compilers are pretty good at handling standard things.

Comment: @eerorika I was just using that as an example, I'm currently using another header guard. Didn't know it was reserved though.

Comment: @Locklan Make sure that the actual header guard isn't reserved as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So for the setup shown above I just need to include the standard library headers in `file.h` if we're taking them as an exception?

Comment: The common recommendation is to not include things that the header itself doesn't need, not to avoid it altogether.

Comment: @eerorika Will do. Also, will removing the prefix and suffix `__` be better when defining header guards?

Comment: @Locklan Yes. Also when defining any name.

Comment: @eerorika Alright, thanks for the help.

Comment: How would your class know how much space it needs to acquire for a new object if it has no idea how much space its members need?

Answer (score 1):

> Given this current setup, how can I implement this so that I can avoid including any header files in the file.h header file?

Member variables of a class must be defined before definition of the class. You can avoid including any files by defining everything in the file.h file.

Standard types are only defined in standard headers and you cannot avoid including those if you want to use them as members. As such, if you want to avoid including headers, then you have to avoid using standard library.

I suppose you could also avoid including headers by importing modules instead. Standard library isn't modular yet though.

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for doing something like this would be to reduce compilation times by minimising include trees (*in this case "file.h" would be pulled in from lots of places, and it will also in turn, pull in lots of other includes*).  It also improves testability/mockability.  Due to the additional complexity, I would only be inclined to use this for "domain level" objects which are accessed via an API (*i.e. do **not** use this where there is sparse usage*).

You can effect this by abstracting `foo` such that only its API is exposed in the header file.  You then implement a subclass which pulls in the includes - but they are only pulled in once.

For more detail I would consult "Large-Scale C++ Software Design" from John Lakos.  Allegedly the older version is better: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Large-Scale-C-Software-Design-APC/dp/0201633620

He has also spoken at various conferences about the new "module" feature: e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EglLjioQ9x0

As a bare minimum example you would have the following.  Obviously it would be better to return a `unique_ptr<foo>`.

file.h

```
#ifndef _FILE_H_672b47fa_7d02_458a_bd42_4774a3765a1b
#define _FILE_H_672b47fa_7d02_458a_bd42_4774a3765a1b

struct foo {
        virtual ~foo() = 0;
        virtual void bar() = 0;
};

extern foo* fooFactory();

#endif
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
#include <...etc...>
...etc...

class fooImpl : public foo {
    private:
        Vector vector; // std::vector from <vector>
        Map map; // std::map from <map>
        ...etc...
    public:
        ~fooImpl();
        void bar() override;
};


void fooImpl::bar() {
    // Do something with private variables...
}

fooImpl::~fooImpl() {
    // cleanup...
}

foo* fooFactory() {
    return new fooImpl();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "file.h"

int main() {
    foo* = fooFactory();
    // Do something...
    delete foo;
}
```

---

An alternative approach, as others have pointed out, would be to encapsulate a separate struct containing the "data" via a member pointer.  It's a valid approach although it could make const-correctness harder to enforce.  It's also related to the flyweight pattern which is useful when the data needs to be passed around different objects, see https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/flyweight

Answer (score 1):

Abstract class or or [pimpl-idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) might avoid to have extra #include:

- Abstract class:

  ```
  #include <memory>

  class fooInterface
  {
  public:
      virtual ~fooInterface() = 0;
      void bar() = 0;
  };

  std::unique_ptr<fooInterface> make_foo();
  ```

  with `foo` remains the same, but in cpp files with additional

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<fooInterface> make_foo() { return std::make_unique<foo>(); }
  ```
- [pimpl-idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl):

  ```
  #include <memory>

  class foo
  {
      struct Impl;
      std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
  public:
      ~foo();
      void bar();
  };
  ```

  and in cpp file:

  ```
  #include <map>
  #include <vector>

  class foo::Impl // Roughly your current `foo`
  {
  private:
      Vector vector; // std::vector from <vector>
      Map map; // std::map from <map>
  public:
      void bar() { /**/}
  };

  foo::~foo() = default; // Here for `foo::~Impl` which should be visible
  void foo::bar() { return impl->bar(); }
  ```

Comment: You're still including <memory> ;-)

Comment: @eerorika: I cannot constraint myself to use raw-owning memory, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You generally can if you instead always include the standard header from the C++ file that uses the class:

```
#include <vector>
#include <custom_stuff_that_references_std_vector.h>
```

The definitions from the previously included files remain valid.

Looks like a useful feature to add to the code obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this first.
[What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

private.h

```
struct fooPrivate
{
Vector vec;
Map m;
}
```

file.h

```
struct fooPrivate;
class foo
{
private:
    fooPrivate *m_ptr;
};
```

file.cpp

```
#include "private.h"
m_ptr = new fooPrivate();  // In constructor
```

You can avoid including any header files in the `file.h`, but you still need to include stl headers in `private.h`.